# Connecting two nodes in a Tree

Tags: trees, tikz-qtree, qtree

[image]

I'm trying to make a simple line connecting the same node. I'm using a simple qtree package.
Here is what I have so far.

```
\Tree
[.\textit{sign} 
[.\textit{syn-sign} \textit{phrase} ]
[.\textit{lex-sign}  [.\textit{word} ]
[.\textit{lexeme} ]]]
```

New question for alignment:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
\begin{forest} qtree edges [\textit{sign},name=sign [\textit{syn-sign}  [\textit{phrase} ] [\textit{word}, name=word,]]    [\textit{lex-sign}, name=lex-sign  [, no edge ] [\textit{lexeme} ]]] 
  \draw (lex-sign.south) -- (word.north); 
\end{forest}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Instead of putting code fragments in your question, it's usually more helpful to post a complete compilable document containing the fragment instead.

Comment: @AlanMunn Thanks that was helpful. Now aligning the word node? Her's what I have \begin{forest}
qtree edges
[\textit{sign},name=sign [\textit{syn-sign}  [\textit{phrase} ] [\textit{word}, name=word,]]
   [\textit{lex-sign}, name=lex-sign  [, no edge ] [\textit{lexeme} ]]]
\draw (lex-sign.south) -- (word.north);
\end{forest}